# Anonymous user cannot access a url pattern which allows anonymous access

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have the following as a part of spring security config.

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAnonymous() or isAuthenticated()" />   
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/another-url" access="isAnonymous() or isAuthenticated()" />
    ...
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
```

I want to let any user access site root "/" and disallow all other urls

With the above config when an anonymous user tries to access site root `/` it redirects user to login

But a user can access `another-url` anonymously without an issue.

This issue is url pattern `/**` overrides `/` and redirecting user to login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configured spring security log level to debug and found that it is trying to match `/index.jsp` when the url is `/`.

After adding intercept-url with pattern `/index.jsp` it started to behave as expected.

```
<security:http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint" disable-url-rewriting="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="isAnonymous() or isAuthenticated()" />   
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/index.jsp" access="isAnonymous() or isAuthenticated()" /> 
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/another-url" access="isAnonymous() or isAuthenticated()" />
    ...
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
</security:http>
```